# Put something on top of the stagewebview with flash builder 4.6

Tags: flash-builder, panel, displayobject, stagewebview

I'm using stagewebview > Flash Builder 4.6

I have a stagewebview and I load an url in it. I want to show sometimes a slide panel on top of the stagewebview.  I tried it, but the panel is always behind the stagewebview. I know that stagewebview isn't a display object, but does anyone know if there is any way I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have the answer, it's a little trickery but I think it's the only way

You need to take a picture of the stagewebview, add the picture to the stage, hide the real stagewebview and THEN you can add something over the top of the pic.

Thanks